# Public api to manage documents in Office Web apps

Tags: .net, web-services

Is there any API or webservices that allows us to manage online Office web apps documents (on sky drive)?

What I would like to do is to use this API (or webservice) in order to create some reports in excel format  without the need to use the [HTML table trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369361/how-can-i-programatically-create-read-write-an-excel-without-having-office-inst/1369413#1369413), neither to have the Excel Com components installed on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such API currently.

You could however use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en), which provides a rich object model on top of System.IO.Packaging and allows generation and manipulation of Office 2007+ files.