# export xls file and microsoft office and oppen office

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

do i need to install Microsoft Excel to be able to export xls file in c#, 
I have my application it run in my pc but when I test it in another pc that it don't contain 
Excel the application got errors !!

I see this link [Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel without actually having Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845770/using-microsoft-office-interop-excel-without-actualy-having-excel), I called my client and he tell me that he use open office and Microsoft office, I can use more than library

Comment: What lib do you use for export?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845770/using-microsoft-office-interop-excel-without-actualy-having-excel

Comment: I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Then follow the link. And, actually, you question is duplicate.

Comment: @Iaroslav Kovtunenko thank you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need you can use some library (free or commercial) for this:

- [OpenXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236) from MS
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/index.html) (commercial)
- [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (commercial)
- [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/847363)