# Convert a website to Html to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, excel

I have the below as part of a web application(asp.net) is there any way to convert it to excel? The problem is printing it. Landscape is the desired format and persons in the organization are very novice so to improve usability i want to allow it to be in landscape. I tried activex and sendkeys commands. This works but not what i desire..

Please help....

[image: Budget Application]

Comment: Copy the table, paste into Excel.

Comment: This wont work because its formatted with css and more than one tables.

Comment: Have you tried? Also, you copy mutiple tables one by one and paste them into separate places on the worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

(1)  Copy + paste.  If there is too much noise then try (2).

(2)  Copy the HTML into a text file, read the text file into a program, have the program parse the HTML in the way that you need it.  From there you should be able to format it as needed or just flat out copy/paste it into Excel.

Comment: @Amarnauth Persaud - thousands if not millions of people scrape websites for data every day. This looks easy to parse into excel from a website using simple querytables/regex/split string etc. It seems you have control over the content so why not allow export to excel as part of your app or redesign the webpage?

Answer (score 2):

Are your pages table-driven (`<table><tr>...`) and not laid out with CSS?  If so, [this has been asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369361/how-can-i-programatically-create-read-write-an-excel-without-having-office-inst).  Excel can consume tabular HTML like a champ.

Comment: It is both tables and standard divs. most are tables...i will try it out.. thank...