# Can I create an Excel sheet using the C# without MS Office installed?

Tags: c#, excel

Can I create an Excel sheet using the C# without having MS Office installed on the host machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I programatically create, read, write an excel without having office installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369361/how-can-i-programatically-create-read-write-an-excel-without-having-office-ins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using the EPPlus library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting Office 2007+ - you can take a look at the the [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Your .xlsm is basically a compressed XML file and as long as you are not doing anything fancy - it should be easy to generate.

If however - you are targeting Office 2003 or earlier - the .xls is a binary format. You might need to look at abiword or star office to see if you can use any of their code to serialize you data to it.

Answer (score -1):

In the past I've created a simple HTML table and saved as .xls and this has opened fine in Excel.

Comment: using the Interop requires Excel to be installed on the host machine.