# Can i create a Microsoft Excel file without using Microsoft Interop Assembly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-office, office-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programatically create, read, write an excel without having office installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369361/how-can-i-programatically-create-read-write-an-excel-without-having-office-ins)

Can i create a Microsoft Excel file without using Microsoft Office Interop Assembly? 
I need to export all the values in a sql server table to an Excel file. Total number of rows can vary between 50000 to 1200000 rows.
I need to generate the Excel file from my C#.net code where i will read the values of the table. The only restriction i have is I cannot use Microsoft Office Interop Assembly.

I can't use CSV, or use the HTML table trick, because some of the files will contain multiple tabs, where each tabs will contain data from different tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369361/how-can-i-programatically-create-read-write-an-excel-without-having-office-ins/1369413#1369413

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to just export your data in a CSV file.  This is beneficial for a number of reasons:

1. CSVs are generally smaller than excel workbooks (read: faster to create via code)
2. Excel can open CSVs just like normal documents and edit them and such.
3. It will be very simple to create a CSV using a few loops and some elbow grease in C#.

The only downfall to this is if you were somehow planning on formatting your data, especially before you got it into a workbook form.

Comment: Good suggestion. One could also launch Excel itself on the csv and use macro's to apply formatting.

Comment: If you need to have specific formatting, you could use XML. That makes it quite complicated though.

Comment: Some of my Excel will contain multiple tabs, where each tabs will contain data from different tables. That is why i did not go for csv file.

Comment: I see.  That makes things a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

http://netoffice.codeplex.com/

Features are (but not only) :

- All features of the Office versions 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 are included.
- No dependencies, no interop assemblies, no need for VSTO
- Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop Assemblies